# Retrieving list of packages imported by each installed applications installed on an android device

Tags: android, android-activity, apk, android-package-managers

Can anybody tell me a way to retrieve the list of packages imported by any android application installed on the device?
I want to develope an application where I want to check if any installed application is using adware packages, so for checking this I want a list of packages imported by any particular application installed on the device.

I have written following code to get list of installed applications

```
    try {
        mPkgMngr = getPackageManager();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mPkgMngr = null;
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    try {
        mPackages = mPkgMngr.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA); 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        mPackages = null;
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

I am able to obtain packageInfo and applicationInfo also using following methods

```
    try {
        mCurAppInfo = mPkgMngr.getApplicationInfo(
                                                PackageName,
                                                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA
                                            );
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        mCurAppInfo = null;
        mCurPkgInfo = null;
        return false;
    }

    try {
        mCurPkgInfo= mPkgMngr.getPackageInfo(
                                                PackageName,
                                                PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES | PackageManager.GET_SERVICES |
                                                PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS | PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS |
                                                PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS
                                            );
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        mCurAppInfo = null;
        mCurPkgInfo = null;
        return false;
    }
```

Can I make use of the information retrieved above to get list of packages imported by an application?
If not, can anyone suggest me any other method?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no requirement to import any packages to use "adware", and there is no way to retrieve the list of imports except perhaps by decompiling.

Comment: Is there any way to check if any "adware sdk" was used while developing an application?

Comment: Generally speaking, no, because there is no absolute definition of "adware sdk". For example, you might be thinking "they are using an 'adware sdk' if they use such-and-so JAR". However, JARs can be renamed, and so a JAR name is not a reliable indicator. Similarly, you might be thinking that "they are using an 'adware sdk' if they reference such-and-so classes". However, Java classes can be renamed, and so a class name is not a reliable indicator.